# Why can't I SELECT a parent field that doesn't have a child?

Tags: select, foreign-keys, parent

(rest_branches) is the table of restaurants.

(phone_numbers) is another table which contains the restaurants phone_numbers, and it has a field called (branch_id) which references the restaurant id.

When I try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM rest_branches
NATURAL JOIN phone_numbers
```

I only get the restaurants which have a phone_number.
What should I do to get all restaurants even if they don't have a phone number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [that's how INNER/NATURAL joins work](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).  If you wanted to get all restaurants, use a LEFT JOIN instead and specify the join condition.